# How to limit number of rows in a table per foreign key in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am dealing with huge numbers, so I decided to limit number of rows stored in database per foreign key. Say, a table `clicks` looks like this

### Clicks

```
id | site_id | income | date_accessed
-------------------------------------------
1  | 2       | 0.014  | 2013-10-24 14:31:58
2  | 2       | 0.021  | 2013-10-25 22:21:17
3  | 1       | 0.019  | 2013-10-24 19:12:41
```

So assumed there are millions of clicks per "*week*" per site_id, this table is going to be really huge. We decided to limit rows per `site_id` to say 30, so only last 30 clicks will be saved.

A problem is that I do not understand how to handle such situation. Should I be using non-mysql language like PHP to do this calculation and data removal before saving a new record or something else?

I ask to help me understand which way should such a task be solved. Thanks.

Comment: Use a trigger to delete the older rows.

Comment: How about saving just the most recent date_accessed and have a click_counter column that is incremented and have the income a running total.